# ProgrammingError: (1064, 'You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax

Tags: python, html, mysql, string, unicode

I'm making a simple crawling program with python. So, I used MySQL,Python. But when I executed this simple program, a error occurs. And then the contents that were crawled from web weren't updated on MySQL table. This error message shows ProgrammingError and syntax error. But I don't think I typed wrong code. Because there are HTML tag in the problem point. Why HTML tab occur in the error message. I think there are something problem between MySQL and Python. here is the error message.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "crawl.py", line 237, in <module>
    parseArticle( u )
  File "crawl.py", line 166, in parseArticle
    db.updateURL( url , contents )
  File "crawl.py", line 206, in updateURL
    self.cursor.execute("UPDATE urls SET state=%d,content='%s' WHERE url='%s'"%(state,content,url))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 174, in execute
    self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 36, in defaulterrorhandler
    raise errorclass, errorvalue
ProgrammingError: (1064, 'You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near \'\xeb\x8f\x8b\xec\x9b\x80\', dotum, sans-serif; }\r\n\t//--&gt;\r\n\t</style>\n<p style="TEXT-ALIGN: center\' at line 1')
```

And here is the source code. thank you for seeing my help.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import robotparser
import urllib2
import time, traceback, re, sys, os
import MySQLdb

crawler_name = 'daum_blog_crawler'     
mainpage = 'http://blog.daum.net/'      

rp = robotparser.RobotFileParser( mainpage + 'robots.txt' )
rp.read()

def canFetch( url ):
        return rp.can_fetch( crawler_name, url )

def getContent( url, delay=1):
        time.sleep( delay )

        if not canFetch( url ):
                print 'This url can NOT be fetched by our crawler :', url
                return None
        try:
                opener = urllib2.build_opener()
                opener.addheaders = [('User-agent',crawler_name)]
                contents = opener.open(url).read()
        except:
                traceback.print_exc() 
                return None
        return contents

def getArticleInfo( soup ):

        rBlog = re.compile('.+blog.daum.net/\w+/\d+.*?')
        URLs = soup('a',{'href':rBlog})

        return [ u.get('href').split('?')[0] for u in URLs ]

def getOwnArticles( contents ):           
        ret = []
        soup = BeautifulSoup( contents )
        rBlog = re.compile('.+/BlogTypeView.+')
        for u in soup('a',{'href':rBlog}):
                href = u.get('href')
                article = href.split('articleno=')[1].split('&')[0]
                if ret.count(article)<1:
                        ret.append( article )
        return ret

def gatherNeighborInfo( soup ):

        rBlog = re.compile('http://blog.daum.net/\w+')
        Neighbors = soup('a',{'href':rBlog})
        cnt = 0
        for n in Neighbors:
                url = n.get('href')
                blogname = url.split('/')[-1]
                if url and url.startswith('http://') and db.isCrawledURL(url)<1:
                        db.insertURL( url, 1 ) 

                        url2 = getRedirectedURL( url )
                        if not url2: continue
                        re_url = 'http://blog.daum.net' + url2
                        body = getContent( re_url, 0 )
                        if body:
                                for u in getOwnArticles( body ):

                                        fullpath = 'http://blog.daum.net/'+blogname+'/'+u
                                        cnt+=db.insertURL( fullpath )

        if cnt>0: print '%d neighbor articles inserted'%cnt

def getRedirectedURL( url ):
        contents = getContent( url )
        if not contents: return None

        #redirect
        try:
                soup = BeautifulSoup( contents )
                frame = soup('frame')           
                src = frame[0].get('src')
        except:
                src = None
        return src

def getBody( soup, parent ):

        rSrc = re.compile('.+/ArticleContentsView.+')
        iframe = soup('iframe',{'src':rSrc})
        if len(iframe)>0:
                src = iframe[0].get('src')
                iframe_src = 'http://blog.daum.net'+src


                req = urllib2.Request( iframe_src )
                req.add_header('Referer', parent )
                body = urllib2.urlopen(req).read()
                soup = BeautifulSoup( body ) 
                strbody= str(soup.body)
                return strbody   
        else:
                print 'NULL contents'
                return ''

def parseArticle( url ):

        article_id = url.split('/')[-1]
        blog_id = url.split('/')[-2]

        #for debugging, temp
        if blog_id.isdigit():
                print 'digit:', url.split('/')

        newURL = getRedirectedURL( url )

        if newURL:

                newURL = 'http://blog.daum.net'+newURL
                print 'redirecting', newURL
                contents = getContent( newURL, 0 )
                if not contents:
                        print 'Null Contents...'

                        db.updateURL( url, -1 )
                        return


                soup = BeautifulSoup( contents )


                gatherNeighborInfo( soup )              


                n=0
                for u in getArticleInfo( soup ):
                        n+=db.insertURL( u )
                if n>0: print 'inserted %d urls from %s'%(n,url)


                sp = contents.find('<title>')
                if sp>-1:
                        ep = contents[sp+7:].find('</title>')
                        title = contents[sp+7:sp+ep+7]
                else:
                        title = ''


                contents = getBody( soup, newURL )  


                db.updateURL( url , contents )

        else:
                print 'Invalid blog article...'

                db.updateURL( url, 'None', -1 )

class DB:
        "MySQL wrapper class"
        def __init__(self):
                self.conn = MySQLdb.connect(db='crawlDB', user='root', passwd='qltkd')
                self.conn.query("set character_set_connection=utf8;")
                self.conn.query("set character_set_server=utf8;")
                self.conn.query("set character_set_client=utf8;")
                self.conn.query("set character_set_results=utf8;")
                self.conn.query("set character_set_database=utf8;")
                self.cursor = self.conn.cursor()
                self.cursor.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS urls(url CHAR(150), state INT, content TEXT)')
        def commit(self):
                self.conn.commit()
        def __del__(self):
                self.conn.commit()
                self.cursor.close()

        def insertURL(self, url, state=0, content=None):
                #'/' delete
                if url[-1]=='/': url=url[:-1]
                try:    
                        self.cursor.execute("INSERT INTO urls VALUES ('%s',%d,'%s')"%(url,state,content))
                except:
                        return 0
                else:
                        return 1

        def selectUncrawledURL(self):
                self.cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM urls where state=0")
                return [ row[0] for row in self.cursor.fetchall() ]

        def updateURL(self, url, content, state=1):
                if url[-1]=='/': url=url[:-1]
        self.cursor.execute("UPDATE urls SET state=%d,content='%s' WHERE url='%s'"%(state,content,url))

        def isCrawledURL(self, url):
                if url[-1]=='/': url=url[:-1]
                self.cursor.execute("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM urls WHERE url='%s' AND state=1"%url)
                ret = self.cursor.fetchone()
                return ret[0]

db = DB()

if __name__=='__main__':
        print 'starting crawl.py...'


        contents = getContent( mainpage )
        URLs = getArticleInfo( BeautifulSoup( contents ) )
        nSuccess = 0
        for u in URLs:
                nSuccess += db.insertURL( u ) 
        print 'inserted %d new pages.'%nSuccess


        while 1:
                uncrawled_urls = db.selectUncrawledURL()
                if not uncrawled_urls: break
                for u in uncrawled_urls: 

                        print 'downloading %s'%u
                        try:
                                parseArticle( u )
                        except:
                                traceback.print_exc()
                                db.updateURL( u, -1 )
                        db.commit()
                #bs.UpdateIndex()
```

Comment: What is the actually full SQL statement here? String quoting problem?

Comment: i don't know just ProgrammingError: (1064, 'You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near \'\xeb\x8f\x8b\xec\x9b\x80\', dotum, sans-serif; }\r\n\t//--&gt;\r\n\t</style>\n<p style="TEXT-ALIGN: center\' at line 1')                   and other errors are much the same except html tag part oh the error message.

Comment: You don't know? It is your code, not ours, provide the requested information please. Adding a simple debug print statement is straight-forward. If you can not provide this little piece of information, please avoid programming

Comment: I think the last \ of the string causes problems. Or you have a single quota somewhere ' that breaks the syntax

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can try;

```
self.cursor.execute("UPDATE urls SET state=%d,content='%s' WHERE url='%s'"%(state,self.conn.escape_string(content),url))
```

Comment: Wow!!!! thank you! It works now! This error takes much time from me. But mccakici, Could you please explain to me what was wrong and what I didn't know? If you do that, that will be a great pleasure. thanks.

Comment: your problem is single quota. 
for example;
"UPDATE urls SET state=%d,content='bla' vs vs' ..........
if use escape_string
"UPDATE urls SET state=%d,content='bla\' vs vs' ..........