# Not able to add a column from a pandas data frame to mysql in python

Tags: mysql, python-2.7, pandas

I have connected to mysql from python and I can add a whole data frame to sql by using df.to_sql command. When I am adding/updating a single column from pd.DataFrame, not able udate/add.

Here is the information about dataset, result,

```
In [221]: result.shape
Out[221]: (226, 5)

In [223]: result.columns
Out[223]: Index([u'id', u'name', u'height', u'weight', u'categories'], dtype='object')
```

I have the table already in the database with all the columns except categories, so I  just need to add the column to the table. From these,

[Python MYSQL update statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1307378/python-mysql-update-statement)

[ProgrammingError: (1064, 'You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19288842/programmingerror-1064-you-have-an-error-in-your-sql-syntax-check-the-manual)

```
cursor.execute("ALTER TABLE content_detail ADD category VARCHAR(255)" % result["categories"])
```

This can be successfully add the column but with all NULL values,
and when I was trying this

```
cursor.execute("ALTER TABLE content_detail ADD category=%s VARCHAR(255)" % result["categories"])
```

ends with following error

```
ProgrammingError                          Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-227-ab21171eee50> in <module>()
    ----> 1 cur.execute("ALTER TABLE content_detail ADD category=%s VARCHAR(255)" % result["categories"])

/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mysql/connector/cursor.pyc in execute(self, operation, params, multi)
    505             self._executed = stmt
    506             try:
--> 507                 self._handle_result(self._connection.cmd_query(stmt))
    508             except errors.InterfaceError:
    509                 if self._connection._have_next_result:  # pylint: disable=W0212

/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mysql/connector/connection.pyc in cmd_query(self, query)
    720         if not isinstance(query, bytes):
    721             query = query.encode('utf-8')
--> 722         result = self._handle_result(self._send_cmd(ServerCmd.QUERY, query))
    723 
    724         if self._have_next_result:

/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mysql/connector/connection.pyc in _handle_result(self, packet)
    638             return self._handle_eof(packet)
    639         elif packet[4] == 255:
--> 640             raise errors.get_exception(packet)
    641 
    642         # We have a text result set

ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '=0     corporate
1     corporate
```

I think there is something I am missing with datatype, please help me to sort this out, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot add a column to your table with data in it all in one step. You must use at least two separate statements to perform the DDL first (`ALTER TABLE`) and the DML second (`UPDATE` or `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`).

This means that to add a column with a `NOT NULL` constraint requires three steps:

1. Add nullable column
2. Populate column with values in every row
3. Add the `NOT NULL` constraint to the column

Alternatively, by using a "dummy" default value, you can do it in two steps (just be careful not to leave any "dummy" values floating around, or use values that are meaningful/well-documented):

1. Add column as `NOT NULL DEFAULT ''` (or use e.g. `0` for numeric types)
2. Populate column with values in every row

You can optionally alter the table again to remove the `DEFAULT` value. Personally, I prefer the first method because it doesn't introduce meaningless values into your table and it's more likely to throw an error if the second step has a problem. I *might* go with the second method when a column lends itself to a certain natural `DEFAULT` value and I plan to keep that in the final table definition.

Additionally, you are not parameterizing your query correctly; you should *pass the parameter values to the method* rather than formatting the string argument inside the method call. In other words:

```
cursor.execute("Query with %s, %s, ...", iterable_with_values)  # Do this!
cursor.execute("Query with %s, %s, ..." % iterable_with_values)  # NOT this!
```

Comment: @thomas thanks , I got the following error when I have tried, cursor.execute("UPDATE content_detail SET category=%s", result['categories'])  :
ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '%s' at line 1